# NFS low performance after some activity

Tags: networking, centos7, nfs, pxe-boot, nfs4

I have a Linux cluster with nodes that have NFS mountpoints from a central server (actually the nodes are diskless and are booted over PXE). After some activity on the NFS mountpoints from the nodes, NFS seems to slow down drastically, e.g. ssh logins takes minutes, programs that depend on some files on the nfs share takes minutes to start, etc..

A restart of the nfs service on the server and/or also a reboot of the problematic node(s) solve the problem for a short period of time, however it always show up again soon. (Doing both seems to help a bit longer)

Server and nodes are run with CentOS 7.4 with Linux kernel 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 x86_64 and NFSv4 is used. The storage consists of 4 HDDs which are bundeled as a RAID10 (/dev/sda). The network connection between server and nodes is 1GBit/s each, and there is no evidence for dropped packets so far.

What can be the reason of a very slow reaction of NFS, which depends on former activity?

A shortened output of nfsstat on a node when experiencing a slow reaction of the filesystem gives:

> Client rpc stats:
>
> calls    |  retrans  |  authrefrsh
>   44154157 |  0 |         44154258
>
> Client nfs v4:
>
> null    |     read  |       write  |      commit   |    open     |    open_conf
>   0         0% | 58125     0%  | 422038    1% | 6846      0% | 139899    0% | 0         0%
>
> open_noat   | open_dgrd  |  close   |     setattr  |    fsinfo  |     renew
>   30775986 95%  | 144       0% | 70464     0% | 2639      0% | 9         0% | 0

Output of nfsiostat looks like (for fast nfs):

> op/s        rpc bklog
>   3596.86          0.00
>
> read:            ops/s     |   kB/s        |  kB/op        | retrans       avg RTT (ms)    | avg exe (ms)
>           0.224     |  0.289    |  1.292   |    0 (0.0%)         0.441  |    1.151
>
> write:           ops/s     |   kB/s    |     kB/op     | retrans       | avg RTT (ms)  | avg exe (ms)
>          33.837     | 47.329    |    1.399   |    0 (0.0%)   |   0.452  |     1.406

Output of nfsiostat looks like (for slow nfs):

> op/s    |     rpc bklog
>   183.75  |  0.00
>
> read:            ops/s    |         kB/s   |        kB/op  |       retrans |        avg RTT (ms)  |  avg exe (ms)
>   0.012  | 1.158 | 99.426  |     0 (0.0%) |   2.708  | 16.656
>
> write:           ops/s   |          kB/s  |         kB/op   |      retrans          avg RTT (ms)  |  avg exe    (ms)
>   0.295 |  1.882 |  6.387   |    2 (0.0%)  |  0.448 |  0.560

Here we see much lower ops/s and higher kB/op and avg exe durations.

iostat on the central server (when everything works fine):

> Linux 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64    09/27/2019  _x86_64_    (4 CPU)
>
> avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
>             0.48    0.00    0.37    0.02    0.00   99.12
>
> Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
>   sdb              10.83        40.61        67.55    9423785   15673740
>   sda               0.71         5.67         2.54    1315496     590208
>   sdc              10.47        18.96        67.55    4398709   15673740
>   md127             0.00         0.12         0.00      27241         80
>   md126            10.83        59.42        66.92   13787337   15526832
>   md125             0.00         0.01         0.00       2228          0

and the same when everything is slow (however with no large differences):

> Linux 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64       10/14/2019      _x86_64_        (4 CPU)
>
> avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
>             2.94    0.00    1.03    0.01    0.00   96.02
>
> Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
>   sdb              15.05       261.13        52.53  449712785   90460908
>   sda               0.54         7.23        35.45   12443668   61054912
>   sdc              14.97       257.76        52.53  443917089   90460908
>   md127             0.00         0.02         0.00      27241        112
>   md126            11.57         8.68        51.72   14953949   89075284
>   md125             0.00         0.00         0.00       2228          8

Please tell me if you need any further information.

Comment: Lots more information could be useful. On the server: what are IOPS being done? (`iostat`) What storage backs these spindles and does it have quotas?  How is the memory consumption? (`cat /proc/meminfo`)    On the client: have you traced slow NFS operations such as with http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/nfsslower-bpfcc.8.html  or similar?  On the network between them: what is the slowest link?  Is there evidence of dropped packets?

Comment: I've added some more information, the others will be added later.

Answer (score 1):

My first thoughts are that you might want to [check your iostats](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-troubleshoot-nfs-transfer-latency-issues-using-nfsiostat-in-centos-rhel/) after that, it starts to sound like a caching issue.

Comment: I've added some nfsiostat output to the question, I see no remarkable difference to the stats for states of slow and fast nfs. If I interpret your linked page right the RTT gives the latency which doesn't change?

Answer (score 0):

At the end I solved the problem by updating to CentOS 8. One reason for the problem could be different kernel versions on the nodes, but I cannot check this any longer.